# How to add brightness key to dconf

Tags: 14.04, brightness, dconf

I recently downloaded Ubuntu 14.04 and did a clean installation.
I noticed that Ubuntu 14.04 does not store screen brightness settings.

how can I add a value to dconf to store brightness settings?

I looked at alternate ways of doing this, like using a startup script running `xbacklight -set <percentage-value>`.
However, I feel a more elegant solution would be to add dconf key and store the value set by the user.

PS: I'm quite new to Linux and Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm aware this is a pretty old question and that [Ubuntu 14.04 LST (Trusty Tahr)](https://releases.ubuntu.com/14.04/) don't come with [GNOME](https://www.gnome.org/gnome-3/), since it just came back after [Ubuntu 17.10 (Artful Aardvark)](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/17.10/).

Anyway, for further search about brightness settings on latest versions of Ubuntu, I'll suggest [Soft-brigthness](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1625/soft-brightness/) extension that is pretty simple and do the job!
And, by now, are working properly at newest [Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (Focal Fossa)](https://releases.ubuntu.com/20.04/)

Hope it helps!